# msal.js has issue with mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, azure, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have an issue with MSAL.js , I cannot login using Chrome or Safari on iOS. I managed to log in using Safari and chrome only when I disabled "Prevent cross-site tracking" .
I am using msal.js 2.14.2 .

Do you know a way to fix this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it by using single page application on azure active directory before I was using web application type, it worked for all devices and all browsers .
I used msal-browser version  2.18.0 from [here](https://alcdn.msauth.net/browser/2.18.0/js/msal-browser.min.js)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-third-party-cookies-spas), it is a known issue with MSAL when working with the browsers that are blocking 3rd party cookies.

The solution recommended by Microsoft is to make use of [`authorization code flow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow).

There are a few issues talking about this on MSAL.js GitHub repo: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues?q=Prevent+cross-site+tracking.

I would also recommend that you open a new issue there in case the authorization code flow solution will not work for you.

Comment: thank you for your reply and now I am  following up that information that you attached and once I get a solution , I will raise here .